# Calling object elements from a list of objects

Tags: dart

I'm trying to figure out how to access an element of an object from a list for objects:

```
class ItemData {
  var id;
  var score;
  var title;
  var description;

  ItemData({this.id, this.score, this.title, this.description});
}

//list of all items
var itemList = [
  ItemData(id: 1, score: 30, title: 'mock title', description: 'mock description')
];
```

I am pushing instances of ItemData to itemList and then want to sort them from highest score to lowest score. I suspect I need a for loop but I can't figure out how to print the 'score' element for index[0] of itemList.

Comment: Do you want the list to be kept sorted while you are inserting the elements or do you want to insert all the elements and then sort it?

Comment: Just a note. Your `ItemData` should be typed so Dart know what type it can expect when getting data from your `ItemData` class. I have fixed your class in my examples in my answer.

Comment: I want to keep it sorted while I am inserting elements. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this in my opinion. The first is to insert all your `ItemData` into your `itemList` and then call `sort()` on the list to get it sorted:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class ItemData {
  final int id;
  final int score;
  final String title;
  final String description;

  ItemData({
    required this.id,
    required this.score,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
  });

  @override
  String toString() => '{ID: $id : Score: $score}';
}

void main() {
  final itemList = [
    ItemData(
      id: 1,
      score: 30,
      title: 'mock title',
      description: 'mock description',
    ),
    ItemData(
      id: 2,
      score: 15,
      title: 'mock title',
      description: 'mock description',
    ),
    ItemData(
      id: 3,
      score: 50,
      title: 'mock title',
      description: 'mock description',
    ),
  ];

  print(itemList);
  // [{ID: 1 : Score: 30}, {ID: 2 : Score: 15}, {ID: 3 : Score: 50}]

  itemList.sort((item1, item2) => item2.score.compareTo(item1.score));

  print(itemList);
  // [{ID: 2 : Score: 15}, {ID: 1 : Score: 30}, {ID: 3 : Score: 50}]
}
```

Another solution would be to use a [`SplayTreeSet`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.4/dart-collection/SplayTreeSet-class.html) to make a `Set` of `ItemData` which is automatically sorted as we add more `ItemData` to the set:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class ItemData {
  final int id;
  final int score;
  final String title;
  final String description;

  ItemData({
    required this.id,
    required this.score,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
  });

  @override
  String toString() => '{ID: $id : Score: $score}';
}

void main() {
  final itemSet = SplayTreeSet<ItemData>(
    (item1, item2) => item2.score.compareTo(item1.score),
  );

  itemSet.add(
    ItemData(
      id: 1,
      score: 30,
      title: 'mock title',
      description: 'mock description',
    ),
  );
  print(itemSet);
  // {{ID: 1 : Score: 30}}

  itemSet.add(
    ItemData(
      id: 2,
      score: 15,
      title: 'mock title',
      description: 'mock description',
    ),
  );
  print(itemSet);
  // {{ID: 1 : Score: 30}, {ID: 2 : Score: 15}}

  itemSet.add(
    ItemData(
      id: 3,
      score: 50,
      title: 'mock title',
      description: 'mock description',
    ),
  );
  print(itemSet);
  // {{ID: 3 : Score: 50}, {ID: 1 : Score: 30}, {ID: 2 : Score: 15}}
}
```

The last solution does means your data can be put into a `Set` which means duplicated elements (elements which are considered equal and generates the same hashCode) will be merged.

Comment: I used your first suggested solution to success. One thing I don't understand is the @override String toString() => '{new list}'.  Why does this allow the elements to be printed? If I don't do this I get the list: [Instance of 'ItemData', Instance of 'ItemData', Instance of 'ItemData']

Comment: I added it to make it easier for me to output what the list contains. The `toString()` method is called on a given object to get a `String` representation of the object. When you are using `print()` it calls the `toString()` method on the provided object. In my case, we do it on a `List` (or `Set`) which are then implemented to call the `toString()` on each element they contain to make a full describing string.

Comment: @JeremyParker Please accept the answer if you find it satisfactory. If not, please give a comment about what can be improved or if there are missing details for solving your problem. :)